# Pesquisa de entre datas

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso pesquisar no meu MySQL idade de alguns colaboradores cadastrados. 
Tenho o campo dt_nascimento e preciso por exemplo buscar colaboradores que tenham a idade entre 20 a 30 anos, como posso fazer isso?

Com esse trecho de código consigo as datas, mas infelizmente não é o que preciso, vejam:

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dt_nascimento)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(dt_nascimento,5)) as idade FROM candidato c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após ajuda de muitos, também vou deixar minha colaboração, fiz de uma forma simples e pode ser que também ajuda alguém, vejam:

```
select * from candidato WHERE (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(candidato.dt_nascimento)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(candidato.dt_nascimento,5)) between 38 and 45
```

Answer (score 5):

Segue SQL que leva em conta a data de aniversário:

```
SELECT * FROM candidato
   WHERE dt_nascimento BETWEEN
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR) AND
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

<sub>(quebras de linha adicionadas para melhor ligibilidade)</sub>

Caso precise ajustar a query para excluir ou incluir o dia específico do aniversário, basta usar qualquer um destes ajustes (dependendo se vai usar no primeiro ou no último intervalo):

```
      DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

ou

```
      DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 3):

*A pergunta é sobre a idade dos colaboradores então a primeira SQL é a forma bruta pelo ano e a segunda lhe dá um ano com um cálculo mais aproximado*

### SQL somente com Anos

```
SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dt_nascimento)) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

### SQL com Anos, Meses e Dias

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(datac, 1,2) AS unsigned) Anos, dt_nascimento           
FROM
(
SELECT dt_nascimento, ((date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d') - date_format(dt_nascimento,'%Y%m%d'))) as datac FROM candidato 
) as resultado where 
CAST(SUBSTRING(datac, 1,2) AS unsigned) BETWEEN 30 AND 40
```

**Obs:** *Apesar da pergunta não dizer se ele quer um precisão de meses e dias pelo visto só era ano eu fiz as duas*

Comment: Obrigado Harry Potter, não referenciei a questão da precisão de meses e dias, mas sinceramente me ajudou muito pois analisando o resultado que esta query me proporciona será muito interessante mostrar os valores na resposta da consulta.

Comment: @adventistapr, na tem problema, você não tem culpa de nada, e que bom que ajudou!

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na resposta do Bacco, podemos utilizar a função `CURDATE()` do MySQL para retornar o dia corrente, sem as informações de hora. Assim não temos que nos preocupar em incrementar ou decrementar um dia das datas limites.

A query original do Bacco ficaria assim:

```
SELECT data_nascimento FROM candidato
WHERE data_nascimento >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR) AND
      data_nascimento < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR);
```

Outra alternativa é o uso dos operadores `>=` e `<` ao invés do `BETWEEN`

**Nota:** No caso de uso dos operadores, só funcionará se o campo `data_nascimento` for do tipo data

```
SELECT data_nascimento FROM candidato
WHERE data_nascimento >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR) AND
      data_nascimento < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR);
```

Exemplo das querys no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb63cd/3).

Comment: Pode ser útil criar uma FUNCTION que receba data de nascimento e data de cálculo, calcule e retorne a idade, facilita queries deste tipo na minha opinião.

Comment: http://www.profissionaisdaweb.com.br/calculando-a-idade-diretamento-na-query-9.jsp   exemplo que achei.

Comment: O uso de Functions no `WHERE` não é interessante pois os índices do campo não serão utilizados, deixando a consulta lenta em tabelas com maior número de linhas. Referencia: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,380275,380275#msg-380275

Comment: Creio que terá o mesmo custo que qualquer FUNCTION para calcular a idade, mas só testando.

Comment: A vantagem que vejo é a reutilização de código.