# Pesquisa por idade em campo de data de nascimento

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, tenho uma tabela paciente e  preciso de uma query na qual o usuário informa uma idade e retorna os registros existentes. Porém não tenho o campo idade na tabela e sim data de nascimento.

Comment: De certa forma a pergunta já foi resolvida aqui: 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16643/24260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM paciente
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nascimento, CURDATE()) = idade
```